# Angular: Multiple tab detection with user idle

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have an Angular application. Now it's possible to open new browser tabs of the same app. My goal is to detect, if a new browser tab (infinitive tabs possible) of my app has been opened and to stop, reset or start the user idle's timer. This doesn't work.

I've tried lots of things I found, but nothing worked:

- I used the visibilitychange-event and blur/focus-listener: It only supports 1 tab: So if I leave one tab it just detects that this one isn't focused anymore
- I tried to add an unique id to each browser tab to detect, which browser tab is open and which browser tabs not
- I tried to solve it with the local storage but this didn't work too
- I tried to use another libraries but here the same result as all things I had done before

My final goal is:
The user can open as much tabs of my app as he want. If a new tab is opened and this tab is focused, the idle timer of the unfocused/hidden tabs should be stopped and the idle timer of the focused tap should starting to count. If I close the tab and go to another one, the idle timer should start to count again and the other ones should be stopped.

**As a summary goal:** The idle timer should get executed only in the tab which is opened and in the tabs, which are not in focus, it should get stopped.